# I can't find the errors

Tags: c++, file, error-handling

Write a program that asks the user to enter five floating-point numbers. The program should create a file and save (i.e. write) all five numbers to the file.

Please could any one tell what is the errors here ?

```
#include <iosream>
#include <fstream>
#include <StdAfx.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    float n1,n2,n3,n4,n5;
    ofstream numbersfile;
    numbersfile.open("C:\\x\\numbers.txt");
    cout<<"enter 5 numbres (will be stored to numbersfile)"<<endl;
    cin>>n1 >>n2 >>n3 >> n4 >>n5;

    xfile<<n1 <<n2 <<n3 <<n4 <<n5 <<endl;
    cout<<" your numbers have been written to numbersfile";

    numbersfile.close();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What have you tried? What is the output? Are there any compiler errors? Please provide more information.

Comment: What language (assuming C++)? Is your compiler/IDE throwing an error? If so, what is it? If not, is your program simply not working as expected?

Comment: where did you get the variable `xfile` ?

Comment: if you don't want do get a million downvotes, please read this - http://sscce.org/ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask , and then come back. If you want someone to take time out of their busy day to help you, you should show some level of effort in writing your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
#include <iosream>
```

is spelled wrong. It should read

```
 #include <iostream>
```

xfile is never declared

```
 xfile<<n1 <<n2 <<n3 <<n4 <<n5 <<endl;
```

should be

```
numbersfile<<n1 <<n2 <<n3 <<n4 <<n5 <<endl;
```